# wait for a set of external DAGs within range of execution_date

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG which runs every 5 minutes (lets call it `5_min_dag`) and another DAG which runs daily using the output of some of the `5_min_dag` runs for the day (lets call that `daily_dag`).

How can I ensure that `daily_dag` waits for completion of the `5_min_dag` runs for the current day?

Some simplified code to illustrate the issue:

---

```
# ./5_min_dag.py
5_min_dag = DAG('5_min_dag', schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5))
5_min_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='5_min_task', 
    bash_command="echo date", 
    dag=5_min_dag
)
```

---

```
# ./daily_dag.py
daily_dag = Dag('daily_dag', schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

daily_average_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='daily_average_task', 
    bash_command="~/make_daily_average.py", 
    dag=daily_dag
)

## pseudocode for what I am missing:
# for each 5_min_dag that is "today" (relative to {{execution_date}})
#    set the 5_min_dag upstream of daily_average_task
```

---

Is this possible?

Perhaps using ExternalTaskSensor and/or SubDagOperator?

Answer (score 4):

A better way I have found to solve this issue is to use an `SQLSensor` to query the airflow metadata database.

Firstly, a [connection](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#connections) to the database will need to be set up. I used the web UI to set up the connection called `mysql_default`.

The following operator is set as the first task in the `daily_dag`. It will not succeed until all `5_min_dag`s for the day of the `daily_dag`'s `execution_date` have `status==success`.

```
    wait_for_5_min_dags = SqlSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_all_5_min_dags',
        conn_id='mysql_default',
        sql="""
        SELECT GREATEST(COUNT(state)-287, 0)
            FROM dag_run WHERE
                (execution_date BETWEEN
                    '{{execution_date.replace(hour=0,minute=0)}}' AND '{{execution_date.replace(hour=23,minute=59)}}')
                AND dag_id='5_min_dag'
                AND state='success';
        """
    )
```

`SQLSensor` only succeeds when the query returns a non-empty or non-zero result. So this query is written to return 0 until we find exactly `288` successful dag runs in the day (`24*60/5=288`). If we were waiting for a dag that runs hourly we would subtract `23` because we are waiting for `24` dags per day.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem. I tried using TriggerDagRunOperator when all hourly instances are completed. 
For all hourly instances, the airflow variable gets updated. When no of runs are 23, it will trigger the other dag(daily dag, though other dag will now have schedule_interval=None). You need to set the variable value to 0 again, when you trigger the new dag. (The issues is here if the triggered dag failed then ?)

```
dag = DAG('airflow_examples.hourly_to_daily_dependency_controller', description='DAG which prints Hello World',
              schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
              start_date=datetime(2018, 4, 15), catchup=True, default_args=default_args)

echo_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='echo_hello_world',
        bash_command='echo "in Hourly Dag: Hello"',
        dag=dag)

def update_variable(ts,**kwargs):
        hourly_dag_runs = Variable.get('hourly_dag_runs')
        hourly_dag_runs = int(hourly_dag_runs) + 1
        Variable.set('hourly_dag_runs', hourly_dag_runs)


update_hourly_dag_runs = PythonOperator(
        task_id='update_hourly_dag_runs',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=update_variable,
        dag=dag)

def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
    hourly_dag_runs = Variable.get('hourly_dag_runs')
    if (hourly_dag_runs == "23"):
        dag_run_obj.payload = {'message': hourly_dag_runs}
        Variable.set('hourly_dag_runs', 0)
        return dag_run_obj

trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='test_trigger_dagrun',
                                    trigger_dag_id="airflow_examples.trigger_dailydag_run",
                                    python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
                                    dag=dag)

echo_task >> update_hourly_dag_runs >> trigger
```

Comment: Interesting approach using variables, but like you say it is sensitive to failures and maybe other edge cases. Multi-timescale aggregation is fairly common and I am surprised I have not been able to find a standard approach to this in airflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but I made this work by generating a long list of ExternalTaskSensors:

```
for tdelta in range(0, 288):  # 288 5-minute dags per day (24*60/5=288)
    ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_5_min_dag_'+str(tdelta),
        external_dag_id='5_min_dag',
        external_task_id='5_min_task',
        execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=tdelta),
        dag=daily_dag
    )
```

But that is not going to look very nice and depends on the task within the 5_min_dag, not the dag itself. This means it will not work if `5_min_dag` has branches.

To work with branches the `skipped` state can be allowed as well

```
for tdelta in range(0, 288):  
    ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_5_min_dag_'+str(tdelta),
        external_dag_id='5_min_dag',
        external_task_id='5_min_task',
        allowed_states=['success','skipped'],  # skipped means this branch not followed
        execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=tdelta),
        dag=daily_dag
    )
return daily_dag
```

but then you need a set of these sensors for each branch of the `5_min_dag`.

To prevent filling the GUI with these sensors, they could be wrapped in a subdag.

Another problem with this approach is that it spawns a large number of "wait" tasks all at once which can easily lead to a deadlocked state.

Let's hope someone comes along with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to use a combination of the ShortCircuit Operator and TiggerDagRun Operator in your 5 min DAG.

A(Your Actual Task) -> B(ShortCircuitOperator) -> C(TriggerDagRunOperator)

In the ShortCircuitOperator you can use a python function which will check the execution date and the last execution date of a day for a 5 min dag will be 2018-08-10 23:55:55. You can use python date-time libraries to check if its this time and only then succeed the ShortCircuitOperator.

Now to check if all the previous 5 min runs for the day are a success in the same python function of the ShortCicuitOperator you can write and function using the DagRun class of airflow rather than setting up a separate connection to the airflow database.  So it will look something like

```
DagRun.find(dag_id="5_min_task",
            state=State.SUCCESS,
            execution_date=[all 5 min execution dates])
```

You can run a loop to check the count returned by the above function and sleep in case it doesn't match and keep checking until the desired number of dag runs a match.